# Dropdown on form not updating the record on SubmitForm - Powerapps

Tags: collections, dropdown, submit, lookup, powerapps

I am creating a task list (of sorts) using Powerapps with Sharepoint Lists as a data source.
I have a ‘**Tasks**’ list, which has a column called ‘**AssignedTo**’. This is a lookup column (multi-value) which references a List called ‘**AStaff**’ *(I couldn’t simply use a Person column because I have additional information I want to keep with these records, but the list ‘AStaff’ does have a Person column).*

On my Powerapps ‘Task’ form, I have a dropdown for the user to select values for the ‘**AssignedTo**’ field. Its ‘Items’ property is set to the following, which worked fine...

```
Filter(Choices([@Tasks].AssignedTo),DataCardValue15.SearchText in Value)
```

However, I want the drop-down list to show more information than just the Title from the ‘**AssignedTo**’ lookup, so I decided to use a collection for the ‘**AssignedTo**’ dropdown’s ‘Items’ property so that I could concatenate the person’s Title and their Hub, so it might read “A Smith (S)” instead of just “A Smith”.

This is what I used to create the collection…

```
Collect(AStaffList, AddColumns(AStaff, "DisplayTitle", Concatenate(Title, " (" , Hub.Value, “)”)))
```

The ‘Items’ property of the dropdown was then set to ‘**AStaffList**’ and the ‘Update’ property of the DataCard was set to **DataCardValue15.SelectedItems**

This seems to work okay – i.e. it shows the correct list of names in the dropdown and I can select them - but the selection is not saved to the Task when I submit the form. There are no errors but the ‘**AssignedTo**’ column data in the Task list is unchanged. I suspect that somehow the control has become ‘unbound’ from ‘Tasks’, but I am very new to Powerapps and don’t yet fully understand what’s happening behind the scenes.

Any advice please?

Comment: I recommend the Monitor functionality in PowerApps. Start a monitoring session and perform the update. The Monitor tab will show you the traffic in detail. Perhaps you have to reduce the record sent to SharePoint with the DropColumns() function to match the original schema.

Comment: Thanks @mmikesy90. The Monitor shows "AssignedTo": []  - i.e. empty brackets. I've tried shaping the data by adding & removing columns from the DataCardValue15.SelectedItems property so that the Table being submitted mirrors the Table being submitted in my first iteration (when it worked) but it seems to me that that isn't why Monitor shows no data is being sent for that field.